# Is it possible to apply root motion to non humanoid objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible to apply root motion to non humanoid objects?

I need the object position to be incremental after every animation in animation controller. Position in default is reset to starting point of current clip. How do i prevent this? I need to make animation state machine with part of clips to make incremental changes in objects properties.

Answer (score 4):

From [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RootMotion.html) :

> **Generic Root Motion and Loop Pose**
>
> This works in essentially the same
> as Humanoid Root Motion, but instead of using the Body Transform to
> compute/project a Root Transform, the transform set in Root Node  is
> used. The Pose (all the bones which transform below the Root Motion
> bone) is made relative to the Root Transform.

Apparently yes you can use the RootMotion on non-humanoid objects. You need to set the correct Root node in the Rig section for models and animations, this should be the node that actually contains the root motion that you want applied to your generic model.

[Here's a thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/mecanim-root-motion-for-generic-rig-quadruped.169891/) about it on Unity Forums.

Comment: It appears that root motion is not what I want. It applies position to the whole object. What I want is to have more control over every state transition. Currently while proceeding from state A to B unity restarts state A to beginning instead to immediately move from A's end to B's start. How do I fix that?

Comment: After unchecking: has exit time, the whole animation stops at A's end. What is required to make the transition?

Comment: Does your transition from a to b requires condition ? 
If no then check again Has exit time and make sure that your animation is not looping. you can check this on the animation file.

Comment: It does not require a condition. It is not looping. When I check has exit time to true It jumps again to A's beginning before moving to B's start ...

Comment: The solution is to uncheck "Write defaults" in states in animator. This way animation clips affect only animated values.